# How to count total number of 'HOH' molecules in each file using python

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
path=os.getcwd()
print path
list_of_filenames=os.listdir(path+'//newfiles')
print list_of_filenames
residue=[]
for f in list_of_filenames:
        f1=open(path+'//newfiles//'+f).readlines()
        for line in f1:
                if line.startswith('HETATM'):
                        res_number=line[22:26]
                        if res_number not in residue and line[17:20]=='HOH':
                                residue.append(res_number)
                        else:
                                continue
                else:
                        continue
print(len(residue))
```

Using above script, I got the total number of 'HOH' molecules in all the files as an one value. But I need to know how much of 'HOH' molecules in each file on by one.

So please explain me how this script should be changed according to my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal modification to get each file's occurence.

```
residue=[]
for f in list_of_filenames:
        f1=open(path+'//newfiles//'+f).readlines()
        for line in f1:
                if line.startswith('HETATM'):
                        res_number=line[22:26]
                        if res_number not in residue and line[17:20]=='HOH':
                                residue.append(res_number)
                        else:
                                residue.append(0)  # changed
                else:
                        continue

for i in range(len(residue)):  # print each occurence
    print(residue[i])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. a great help

Answer (score 0):

The following answer will store all of the files into a dictionary and then iterate the number of uses per file.  Go ahead and test it out, comment if you need any more input.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

di = {}

import os
path=os.getcwd()
print path
list_of_filenames=os.listdir(path+'//newfiles')
print list_of_filenames
residue=[]
for f in list_of_filenames:
        f1=open(path+'//newfiles//'+f).readlines()
        di[f] = 0
        for line in f1:
                if line.startswith('HETATM'):
                        res_number=line[22:26]
                        if res_number not in residue and line[17:20]=='HOH':
                                residue.append(res_number)
                                di[f] += 1
                        else:
                                continue
                else:
                        continue
print(len(residue))
print(di)
```

Comment: I think my problem is I'm not using a dictionary. Now I will be used to it. di [f]=0 and di[f]=1. What does it means ?

Comment: di[f] is the dictionary element where th key is f, it sets the value to what follows the = sign

Comment: Updated comment.

Comment: got it.understood well.

Comment: yes of course I accepted your answer because it was very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Separate files should be tracked separately, and to reduce some boilerplate code, use a defaultdict(set), which basically stores a set to each file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
path=os.getcwd()
list_of_filenames=os.listdir(path+'//newfiles')
residue = collections.defaultdict(set)
for f in list_of_filenames:
    with open(open(path+'//newfiles//'+f) as f1:  # close the file
        for line in f1.readlines():
                if line.startswith('HETATM'):
                        res_number=line[22:26]
                        if res_number not in residue[f] and line[17:20]=='HOH':
                                residue[f].add(res_number)
                        else:
                                continue
                else:
                        continue
print(residue)
```

Comment: yes I accept the answer. But I have a small doubt. The output is not that much similar to the required answer. for example it is not showing the total number of residues of each file. such as file1:1000, file2:1500, file3:2000  like that.